# How to read data from array after promise/observable call

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-promise

I am not into javascript and angular, currently working on some UI task and has workable/little knowledge of javascript

what i want, base on a key field filter out the objects.

currently what code is doing, hitting a api, which is storing some result in an array. this array result are in object (promise object) i guess, and i need to set out a filter condition on this object base on some value.

but for me issue is, object does not have key same as response, it store. data like this

```
​Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { _isScalar: false, source: {…}, operator: {…} }
​
1: Object { _isScalar: false, source: {…}, operator: {…} }
​
2: Object { _isScalar: false, source: {…}, operator: {…} }
​
3: Object { _isScalar: false, source: {…}, operator: {…} }
​
4: Object { _isScalar: false, source: {…}, operator: {…} }
​
length: 5
```

so even if i iterate through each object i cant find the key which is my filter criteria.

below is code related to this

```
getSomeThing(
        name: string,
        dcId: any
    ): Promise<any[]> {
        const url = `<url>`;
        return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.sharedService.getHeaders() })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => this.getSomeThingOneByOne(name, dcId, response.json()))
            .catch(error => this.sharedService.handleError(error));
    }
```

```
private getSomeThingOneByOne(name, dcId, someIds): Promise<any> {
        const someObservables = [];
        someIds.forEach(some => someObservables.push(this.getsomethingObservable(name, dcid, some)));
 
        return Observable.forkJoin(someObservables)     
        .toPromise()
        .catch(error => this.sharedService.handleError(error));
    }
```

```
getsomethingObservable(
        name: string,
        dcId: any,
        someId: any
    ): Observable<any> {
        const url = `<url>`;
        return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.sharedService.getHeaders() })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                const vm = response.json();
                return vm;
            })
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(this.sharedService.handleError(error)));
    }
```

note i have change the name of function and variable.,

now here, `getsomeThing` call an api which return a list of ids and pass it to `getSomethingOneByOne` as array ie `[1,2,3,4,5]` , and this function  `getSomethingOneByOne` call `getsomethingObservable` to get the data related to that id.

what i want is once i recied the data i should check a certain value in it or in `getsomethingObservable` check the value it self for that key and filter out the result.
but due since i am not able to read the data in array `someObservables` in function `getSomeThingOneByOne` raw i cant add filter condition there.

need help here as it requires knowledge of promise, obserable, angular and typescript which i lack.

Comment: you should use rxjs operators map, mergeMap, forkJoin to combine them

Comment: here is best example you can use:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-request-handling?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @SonuSindhu forkjoin is happening here in `getSomeThingOneByOne` function, over here of each data object which is present in array `const someObservables = [];` here i need to make the filter condition, since i got no knowledge of typescript i am unable to follow example you provided here

Comment: You can use like that:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzaeuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thank you,  with taking some reference from your source, i was able to make changes in `getSomeThingOneByOne` and after `toPromise` i made `.then` method and added filter condition there. so with that issue is solve now

Answer (score 0):

just solved this by taking reference from @sonusindhu suggestion and taking [reference](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise) from here too.

i had made changes on `getSomeThingOneByOne` as below and it worked

```
private getSomeThingOneByOne(name, dcId, someIds): Promise<any> {
        const someObservables = [];
        someIds.forEach(some => someObservables.push(this.getsomethingObservable(name, dcid, some)));
 
        return Observable.forkJoin(someObservables)     
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
             var data = response.filter(val=>val[<somekey>]!='<a certain value>');
          return data;
})
        .catch(error => this.sharedService.handleError(error));
    }
```